# What is a battery pod?

Tags: fuselage, battery

On a manual in school was written: 'The fuselage battery pod must be made in a metal to improve the impact resistance'.

What is meant with battery pod here?

Comment: Is this about GA planes? Some specific airliner? Military? What's the book title and author? "On a manual .. was written" makes it sound like graffiti, confirm if it is typeset or handwritten?

Answer (score 4):

**The definition of pod is:**  *A detachable or self-contained unit on an aircraft, spacecraft, vehicle, or vessel, having a particular function.*

Therefore a fuselage battery pod would be **a detachable or self contained unit that has the function of containing the battery.**

- Most vehicles with a battery have a means to contain the battery to restrain it from moving.  Some also include a method to vent gasses, and/or contain a battery fire.  I have heard them more commonly referred to as a battery "box", but "pod" would be an acceptable term as well.
- If you do a word search for "aircraft battery pod" you can see some examples.  If your manual is having to do with an EV aircraft with batteries in the fuselage then presumably the requirements might be more stringent than a battery forward of the firewall used to start an internal combustion engine.

If you want more detail than this you will need to offer more context from the manual you mention in your question.

Comment: Good answer.  More info from the OP would help. The fix for the 787 lithium battery problem years ago that grounded the fleet was resolved with a metal/steel fireproof box designed to contain fire. Perhaps this is what is meant by a fuselage battery pod.

Comment: @757toga, thanks and good info!  I added a tweak to my answer to include fire...